# Mathematically showing a field transforms under special conformal transformations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, conformal-field-theory

I'm going over some past papers and came across this exercise:

*A scalar primary field $\phi(x)$ of scaling dimension $\Delta$ transforms under a special conformal transformations as*

$$\delta \phi = 2\Delta x_\nu \phi - K_\nu\phi \tag{1}$$

*where $K_\nu = x^2 \partial_\nu -2 x_\nu x^\mu \partial_\mu$*

*Show that*

$$\delta \left( \phi \partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi \right)= \left( 2x_\nu (2\Delta+2)-K_\nu\right) (\phi \partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi) \hspace{1mm} + \alpha \phi \partial_\nu \phi \tag{2}$$

*where I must determine $\alpha$*

**I attempted to obtain this by doing the following (but the answer it gave me was not the one needed).**

$$\delta \left( \phi \partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi \right)=\phi \partial_\mu \delta \left(\partial^\mu \phi \right) + \delta(\phi\partial_\mu)(\partial^\mu \phi) \tag{3}$$

where

$$\delta(\partial^\mu \phi) = \partial^\mu \delta \phi + (\delta \partial^\mu)\phi \hspace{5mm} ; \hspace{5mm} \partial(\phi\partial_\mu )= \phi \delta \partial_\mu + (\delta \phi) \partial_\mu \tag{4}$$

$$$$

$$\delta(\partial^\mu \phi) =\partial^\mu( 2\Delta x_\nu \phi - K_\nu\phi )+ \partial^\mu (2\Delta x_\nu \phi - K_\nu \phi ) + (2\Delta x_\nu \partial^\mu -K_\nu \partial^\mu)\phi$$

$$= \partial^\mu( 2\Delta x_\nu \phi - K_\nu\phi ) + (2\Delta x_\nu \partial^\mu -K_\nu \partial^\mu)\phi $$

$$= 2\Delta \delta^\mu_\nu \phi -x^\mu \partial_\nu \phi - 2 x_\nu \partial_\mu \phi+ (2\Delta x_\nu \partial^\mu \phi -x^2 \partial_\nu \partial^\mu \phi - 2 x_\nu x^\mu \partial_\mu)$$

$$$$

$$\hspace{5mm} \partial(\phi\partial_\mu )=\phi(2\Delta x_\nu \partial_\mu -K_\nu \partial_\mu)+ (2\Delta x_\nu \phi -K_\nu \phi )\partial_\mu$$

$$ =\phi 2\Delta x_\nu \partial_\mu -\phi x^2 \partial_\nu \partial_\mu -\phi 2 x_\nu x^\mu \partial_\mu \partial_\mu + 2\Delta x_\nu \phi \partial_\mu -x^2 \partial_\nu \phi \partial_\mu  - 2x_\nu x^\mu \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\mu $$

I know these are a lot of terms, but they do not give me the solution I need.

**Is there a simpler way of doing these calculations? Or did I make ignorant mistakes?**

Comment: What is $\alpha$ in $(2)$ (v1)? A typo?

Comment: Sorry,forgot to describe it. I will edit it.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense, that operator cannot transform in four $\phi$'s. There should be a $+$ between $\alpha$ and the rest. Double check the text of the excercise.

Comment: I keep on making mistakes, thank you